# C How to Capitalize character after punctuation mark without Arrays?

Tags: c, string, loops

I am very new to the C programming language and was curious how would you capitalize a letter in a program following a punctuation mark without using an array. I tried using the ASCII code values by subtracting 32 but it just doesn't seem to work in my code. Here is a portion of my code that outputs the letters. I thought word = word - 32 would work but it does nothing when running the program. I'd appreciate the help!

```
while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
        if (word == ' ' || word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&' || word == ';' || word == ':'){
            printf("\n");
            word = word - 32;
        }

        if ((word >= 'A' && word <= 'z')){
            printf("%c", word);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it C or C# ?
Also, you want to capitalize the letter **after** the punctuation mark, but your code tries to do it for the letter which itself is a punctuation mark! Use a debugger.

Comment: Programmin in C not C++

Comment: @Johnson - C, C++ and C# are three different Languages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  For some code sets, `word - 32` would actually convert a lower-case letter to the corresponding upper-case letter, but there is no mapping for punctuation characters that makes sense. And the subtraction is a bad idea for case-conversion; you should use the facilities from `<ctype.h>` such as `tolower()` instead. You probably need to keep a record of when you see a punctuation character, and then when you next see a letter, case-convert it to upper case (and set the flag back to 'not after punctuation'). There's an `ispunct()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag to check whether the last entry was a punctuation, and then alter the next input based on the flag and reset it again

```
char word;int flag=0;
while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
    if(flag==1){
        printf("\n");
        word = word - 32; flag=0;
    }
    if (word == ' ' || word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&' || word == ';' || word == ':'){
      flag=1;
    }

    if ((word >= 'A' && word <= 'z')){
        printf("%c", word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you should generally not create your own symbols that start with an underscore.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers says, in part: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use._
— _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._  It's a little more nuanced than "don't use leading underscores", but not by much.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for the insight, and I will take care of this scenario

Comment: Since when does one capitalize after an `&` symbol?

Comment: @RedX: since the question asked you to.  You also capitalize after a blank, too.  In fact, the question has a devious definition of punctuation.  And it generates lots of newlines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hmmmm, ok then.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for that variable naming convention insight I was in a habit of using the same, will now keep in mind :)

Comment: "flag" is a horrible variable name though and integer-based booleans is 1980s programming. Use `bool last_punct;` or similar.

Comment: @Lundin I will agree "flag" is a horrible name. However, `bool` is an integral type, so I'm not sure what the issue is with the variable being an integer.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That bool is an integer in C is mainly a language bug. It is good style to write C code as if the language had a real boolean type. If you do so, you can also gain additional type safety by running the code through static code analysers. (And bool is likely a small integer type so you'll save a little bit of memory)

Comment: @Lundin Any Boolean variable should have its value tested using `if (booleanX)` or `if (!booleanX)`. `if (booleanX == 1)` and `if (booleanX == false)` are overly verbose and consequently wrong in my opinion since a Boolean value by definition cannot have any value other than true or false. If `int booleanX = 2;` is declared, then `booleanX` is true. `(booleanX << 1) | booleanY` is the only scenario in which I might see a problem arise, but I'd say there are issues in the usage of the Boolean value if that expression leads to problems, not with the type chosen to store the value.

Comment: The advantage provided by `_Bool` in such a context is useful only in hiding these sorts of issues within the code. I'm not saying `_Bool` itself isn't useful, but using it for behavioral purposes rather than for its semantic purpose is IMHO the wrong application of the type. However, that debate is for philosophers to sort out.